# Trying to get the button input to work while a loop happening

Tags: python

im here working on a traffic light with an working intersection and i'm basically done with my code and i can't seem to get my button to work for my traffic light. here is my code for my assignment

```
 ` import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#LED setup and Button
led = [19,13,6,22]
button = 21

# GPIO output channel 
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)


#on and off function


#Run traffic light loop till button is pressed. Red=19,yellow=6,green=13.
try:
    while True:
            GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(7)
            GPIO.output(19,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(13,GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(10)
            GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(3)
            GPIO.output(6,GPIO.LOW)

#When button is pressed
    if (GPIO.input(button) == False):
            for i in range (0,16, 1):
                GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
                time.sleep(.25)
                GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(.25)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Reset Program")

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()`
```

can someone help explain to me what is happening?

Comment: What is happening when the button is pressed? If nothing is happening, then you need to change `if (GPIO.input(button) == False):` to `True`.

Comment: `while True:` traps the program forever, it never even checks the input button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very hard to diagnose if you haven't provided any runtime errors. Assuming that your code is running fine without errors and that you have all the wires hooked up the right way (see https://pinout.xyz/ for connecting to the right header pins based on BCM value) then we check the code.

By the looks of it if you have the indentation the way it is, you have your if statement for button press outside an infinite loop (`while True`) and so it won't actually ever check to see if the button is pressed, as after it finishes going through the lights it'll just start again!

Below I've written a suggested updated script, which also makes the code a little more readable. *Note, I have suggested a change of pins to ones better suited to generalised GPIO usage*.

As a side note, you might want to check out [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
as an alternative to the standard GPIO library on Pi.

## New code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# LED setup and Button

red_led = 17  # bcm 17 = header pin 11
yellow_led = 27  # bcm 27 = header pin 13
green_led = 22  # bcm 22 = header pin 15
other_led = 23  # bcm 23 = header pin 16
button = 24  # bcm 24 = header pin 18

# GPIO output channel

GPIO.setup(red_led, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(green_led, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(yellow_led, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(other_led, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Run traffic light loop till button is pressed.
# Red=0, Green=1, Yellow=2

light = 0
def change_lights():
    global light, red_led, green_led, yellow_led
    light = (light+1)%3  # each call iterates one step through a 0,1,2 loop
    if light == 0:
        GPIO.output(red_led,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(yellow_led,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(green_led,GPIO.LOW)
    elif light == 1:
        GPIO.output(red_led,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(yellow_led,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(green_led,GPIO.HIGH)
    elif light == 2:
        GPIO.output(red_led,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(yellow_led,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(green_led,GPIO.LOW)

def button_pressed():
    global other_led
    for i in range(16):
        GPIO.output(other_led, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(.25)
        GPIO.output(other_led, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(.25)

try:
    GPIO.output(red_led,GPIO.HIGH)
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()  # marks the current time
        # we now poll the current time at the same time as
        # polling to see if the button was pressed
        while time.time() < start_time+7:
            if (GPIO.input(button) == False):
                button_pressed()

        change_lights()  # we cycle to the next light

        start_time = time.time()  # reset the start time
        while time.time() < start_time+10:
            if (GPIO.input(button) == False):
                button_pressed()

        change_lights()  # we cycle to the next light

        start_time = time.time()  # reset the start time
        while time.time() < start_time+3:
            if (GPIO.input(button) == False):
                button_pressed()

        change_lights()  # we cycle to the next light

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Reset Program")
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Apologies as I can't guarantee the code will run perfectly as is, don't have easy access to my Pi and electronics right now.

The alternative to polling both the button and time is to use interrupts (which I wouldn't recommend on such a simple application.

Ps. generally using global variables is not good practise, but I think you can get away with it on this one...

Comment: thank you so much Nebbles! this made it more understanding to me and it works properly. i was just getting confused on the indentation because that's what my professor was telling me too but no error popped up about it.

Comment: No problem, if it answered you Q please consider ticking it :) also would strongly recommend you checkout gpiozero